# How to set the fields simultaneously in a large structure array in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, structure

I have a large structure array.

I would like to perform a sensitivity analysis on a function that processes this array.

So, say my structure array has name 's', 10,000 elements, and field names 'x' and 'y'.

I'd like to do the following:

```
xs = [s(:).x];
xs = xs + 5*randn(size(xs));
s(:).x = xs;
```

Sadly, the last step is not valid matlab.  Any thoughts?  Was hoping to avoid a loop.

Comment: Please refer to: [Updating one field in every element of a Matlab struct array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303070/updating-one-field-in-every-element-of-a-matlab-struct-array)

Comment: I suspect the problem is that even if Matlab **could** handle an expression like that, it's not clear whether each array element `s(i).x` should contain the entirety of `xs` or just a single element from `xs`

Answer (score 0):

[From this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303070/updating-one-field-in-every-element-of-a-matlab-struct-array) and after playing around with deal. I think I have what you are looking for but it requires converting xs into a cell array using `num2cell`:

```
xs_cell = num2cell(xs); % convert matrix to cell array.
[S(:).X]=xs_cell{:}; % update the values in the field X
```