# "Reverse" of arrayfun

Tags: matlab, structure

I have an array of "object" structures, `OBJECT_ARRAY`,  that I must often transform into individual arrays for each element of the object structures. This can be done using `arrayfun`. It's more tedious than simply refereeing to `OBJECT_ARRAY(k).item1`, but that's how The Mathworks chose to do it.

In this case today, I have used those individual arrays and calculated a corresponding derived value, `newItem`, for each element and I need to add this to the original array of structures. So I have an array of `newItems`.

Is there a straightforward way to do an assignment for each object in `OBJECT_ARRAY` so that (effectively) `OBJECT_ARRAY(k).newItem = newItems(k)` for every index `k`?

I am using version 2015a.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating one field in every element of a Matlab struct array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303070/updating-one-field-in-every-element-of-a-matlab-struct-array)

Comment: I had voted to close as a dupe, but @Suever added a more complete answer while I was marking it. Removing dupe vote.

Comment: Please refrain from using a plethora of markdown styles for (pseudo-)code, but use the designated code markdown for that. That way people actually understand what is code and what is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't need `arrayfun` for any of this.

To get values out, you can simply rely on the fact that the dot indexing of a non-scalar `struct` or object yields a [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html). If we surround it with `[]` it will horizontally concatenate all of the values into an array.

```
array_of_values = [OBJECT_ARRAY.item1];
```

Or if they are all different sizes that can't be concatenated, use a cell array

```
array_of_values = {OBJECT_ARRAY.item1};
```

To do *assignment*, you can again use the comma separated list on the left and right side of the assignment. We first stick the new values in a cell array so that we can automatically convert them to a comma-separated list using `{:}`.

```
items = num2cell(newitems);
[OBJECT_ARRAY.item1] = items{:};
```